# How do I stream or scrape a playlist from playlists.net?

Tags: export

In the site [playlist.net](http://playlists.net/upbeat-indie-2013-vol-5) there is a button "Play Now"

It asks me to open Spotify to play. How can I play that list without Spotify?

Or how can I gen a text-based export of the playlist somehow?

Each Entry in that list looks like this in html:

```
<ul class="track-info">
        <li rel="3:44" class="duration">3:44</li>
        <li rel="18. Let it Down" class="track-title 1LOiTXtJUQIvwiWGX70HpI ellipsis">18. Let it Down</li>
        <li style="" rel="Cowboy Indian Bear" class="artist 1LOiTXtJUQIvwiWGX70HpI ellipsis">Cowboy Indian Bear</li>
</ul>
```

maybe you can scrape the title and artist somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If someone has Spotify, you can select "HTTP link" in the playist and send that to your friend as email:

You need to use a service like the Gmail web interface, that converts all links automatically to link names by target.

So just copy the HTTP link in Spotify and paste it for example in Gmail into a new email, then you get a text-playlist.

You can listen to that playlist then for example via http://rdio.com and import it via http://soundiiz.com/

Another site that converts Spotify lists directly seems not to be working anymore: http://groovylists.com/

Here I added all files of "Upbeat Indie 2013 Vol. 5" manually: https://rd.io/i/QTOiQzMxPl4/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a playlist.net user, but I just had a quick look and by reading the [about](http://playlists.net/about) page I doubt that you can. The site is totally based on Spotify. It states:

***What Is Playlists.net All About?***

*Playlists.net is a resource for Spotify users to share and explore Spotify Playlists.*

The embedded audio player, is the one from Spotify.

Comment: maybe scrape it then somehow?

Comment: Wait, so now you want to scrape the playlist, NOT play it, right? There are many different ways of parsing a website. Depending on which programming language you are comfortable with, the answer would be different. Please note that this might be against playlists.net terms of use.

Comment: I think that would be OK: http://playlists.net/terms-of-use "Subject to strict compliance with these Terms, we grant you a limited, personal, non-exclusive, non-commercial, revocable, non-assignable and non-transferrable licence to: use the Site and/or App and to view, download for caching purposes only, and print pages from the Site for your own personal use,."